# How to "POST" the JSON data form Salesforce to the external URL of php and fetch into Php

Tags: php, json, web-services, salesforce

```
public with sharing class Util{

    @future (callout=true)
    public static void callWebservice(SET<Id> cont){       

        List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, LastName, FirstName FROM Contact WHERE Id = :cont];

        String jsonOrders = JSON.serialize(contacts);

        // debugging call, which you can check in debug logs
        System.debug('jsonOrders: ' + jsonOrders);
        // create an HTTPrequest object

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        // set up the HTTP request with a method, endpoint, header, and body      
        req.setMethod('POST');  
        req.setEndpoint('//xyz.com/mastercopytest/salesforce/salesforce_cron.php');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        req.setBody(jsonOrders);    
        // create a new HTTP object
        Http http = new Http();

        System.debug('Request Data '+ req);

        // create a new HTTP response for receiving the remote response      
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

        // debugging call, which you can check in debug logs
         System.debug('Fulfillment service returned '+ res.getBody());


         System.debug('getStatusCode '+ res.getStatusCode());

        // If status code != 200, write debugging information, done
        if (res.getStatusCode() != 200) {
            System.debug('Error from ' + req.getEndpoint() + ' : ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' ' + res.getStatus());
        }        

    }
}
```

Now I want to fetch the posted JSON data in php.I am unable to fetch the data from php. Is there anything i am missing here?How to read post JSON data in php. It is showing empty array on php.Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fetch the json data in php by using                                       $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me in Apex Class

```
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

     JSONGenerator gen = System.JSON.createGenerator(true);  

     gen.writeStartObject();      
     gen.writeStringField('client_id', 'ABCDE');
     gen.writeStringField('client_secret', 'EDFCHH');

     gen.writeEndObject();    

     String jsonS = gen.getAsString();


     req.setEndpoint('https://yourservice.com/api');
     req.setMethod('POST');
     req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     req.setBody(jsonS );

     Http http = new Http();
     HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
     String jsonstr = res.getBody();
```